# Call restController in asynchronous method with vaadin

Tags: spring, rest, vaadin, vaadin14

I have some problem with firing RestController when I want to fire it from a Thread. I'm trying to send a request to RestController from my thread but I don't get any response from the controller when my restTemplate is executing destination URL. RestController isn't even executed. It is working as expected only if I'm sending a request from `ui.access->rest.sendRequest()`, but then my application must wait for the end of the request anyway.

I'm working with Vaadin 14. I created a thread with a run method like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Long> nonBlocking = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restTemp.getForObject("http://localhost:4240/Servis/api/address",
    Long.class));
nonBlocking.thenAccept(s -> {
    if (s != null) {
      ui.access(() -> Notification.open("long is not null"));
    } else {
      ui.access(() -> Notification.open("long is null"));
    }
});
nonBlocking.get();
```

But my code from the rest controller is still not executed.

Comment: What vaadin version?
You can/must send the REST request in a separate thread and block/update the UI after the thread has done it's work

Comment: Complementing what @AndréSchild said. You need to wrap the REST call for example inside CompletableFuture. Call ui.access to update the UI in the thenAccept block of the future.

Comment: i changed RestTemplate to WebClient and now i can send requests asynchronously

Comment: If that solved your problem and you have time, it would be nice if you could write your solution in an answer and mark it accepted. Might help someone else to discover the solution in turn (right now this question shows up as unanswered, and comments often get overlooked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it work as expected when i replaced RestTemplate with WebClient